# Proof that rational sequence converges to irrational number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $a>0$ be a real number and consider the sequence $x_{n+1}=(x_n^2+a)/2x_n$.

I have already shown that this sequence is monotonic decreasing and thus convergent, now I have to show that $(\lim x_n)^2 = a$ and thus exhibit the existence of a positive square root of $a$. (because we took $x_1 > 0$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2x_n$ and take limits. Use that $\lim x_{n+1}=\lim x_n$, that $\lim x_nx_{n+1}=(\lim x_n)(\lim x_{n+1})$, $\lim x_n^2=(\lim x_n)^2$, and $\lim(x_n^2+a)=a+\lim x_n^2$.

Comment: Don't you need to define a base term for $x_n$?

Comment: @user99680 what do you mean by "base term" ?

Comment: @terribleatmath: If the sequence is a recursion, you usually define $x_0$, or $x_1$. Otherwise, how would you find the value of, say $x_2$ in the definition?

Comment: we're given that $x_1$ is any positive rational number.

Comment: Ah, O.K, thanks.

Comment: This is just nit-picking, but if you choose $x_0$ sufficiently small then $x_1$ will be greater than $x_0$, but after that you get a monotonic decreasing sequence starting at $x_1$. The reasoning is that this sequence represents Newton's method applied to the the function $f(x)=x^2-a$, and if $x_0$ is smaller than $\sqrt{a}$ then the tangent line of $f$ at $x_0$ will make us choose $x_1$ to the right of $\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done the hardest part. Let $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=x$. Rearranging the recursion formula gives
$$2\cdot x_n\cdot x_{n+1}=x_n^2+a$$
Taking limits and noting that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n+1}=x$, we have
$$
2x^2=x^2+a
$$
so $x^2=a$.

Answer (score 3):

If $x_n\to x$, then 
$$
x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n^2+a}{2x_n} \to a
$$
as well. But
$$
\frac{x_n^2+a}{2x_n} \to \frac{x^2+a}{2x}.
$$
Thus the limit $x$ satisfies the equation
$$
x=\frac{x^2+a}{2x} \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad 2x^2=x^2+a
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x^2=a \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad x=\pm \sqrt{a}.
$$
But as the sequence has terms terms it can not converge to a negative number. Thus $x_n\to\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive definition can be solved exactly. Write a^2 instead of a and consider the sequence $(x(n)+a))/(x(n)-a)$.
Then $(x(n)+a)/(x(n)-a) =
= (.5*x(n-1)+.5*a^2/x(n-1)+a)/(.5*x(n-1)+.5*a^2/x(n-1)-a) =
= (x(n-1)^2+2*a*x(n-1)+a^2)/(x(n-1)^2-2*a*x(n-1)+a^2) =
= ((x(n-1)+a)/(x(n-1)-a))^2 =$

Thus $(x(n)+a)/(x(n)-a) = ((x(0)+a)/(x(0)-a))^{(2^n)}$.

This proves (very) rapid convergence to +a whenever $|x(0)-a)|<|x(0)+a)|$ and to -a whenever$|x(0)+a)|<|x(0)-a)|$. This holds even when a is complex and complex sequences are considered. You could work out, for instance, the case of a purely imaginary root and real starter $x(0)$...

PS: This works only in this (Babylonian) case.