# Sequence of rational numbers converging to an arbitrary irrational number $\beta$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here is the sequence of irrational number that converges to $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}$.
Take $x_n=\alpha -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$. Clearly $\{x_n\}\rightarrow\alpha .$

But I'm trying to find a sequence of rationals that converges to arbitrary irrational number $\beta$.
Can you give me such a sequence.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/670083/proof-that-rational-sequence-converges-to-irrational-number

Comment: I believe that the "uncountable majority" of irrational numbers cannot be represented with such sequence of rational numbers. Specifically, I am referring to all those that are **not** [computable numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/462795/131263), which gives an example of such number.

Comment: @barakmanos: I don't think computability is relevant here. Petite Etincelle's answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take $\dfrac{\lfloor 10^n \beta\rfloor}{10^n} $ for example, then we have

$$\dfrac{10^n \beta -1}{10^n} \leq\dfrac{\lfloor 10^n \beta\rfloor}{10^n} \leq \dfrac{ 10^n \beta}{10^n}=\beta $$

Since $\dfrac{10^n \beta -1}{10^n} = \beta - \dfrac{1}{10^n} \to \beta$, by squeeze theorem, we have $\dfrac{\lfloor 10^n \beta\rfloor}{10^n}  \to \beta$

Comment: I thought about it but I couldn't.

Comment: @user194772 I've added details

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle Is there anything special about chosing $10^{n}$?? Will $x_{n} = \frac{[a^{n}\beta]}{a^{n}}$ where $a \in N$ and $a>2$ work??

Comment: @S.C. nothing is special with $10$, other examples that you mentioned work as well

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\{x_n\}$ where $x_n={[n\beta]+1 \over n}$  $\forall n \in \mathbb N$.

$[n\beta]<n\beta<[n\beta]+1$  $\forall n \in \mathbb N \Rightarrow \frac{[n\beta]}{n}<\beta<x_n$.

Again $\frac{[n\beta]}{n}<\beta \Rightarrow x_n=\frac{[n\beta]+1}{n}<\beta+{1 \over n}$. Thus $\beta<x_n<\beta+\frac  1n$  $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. By sandwich theorem $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =\beta$.