# Sequence of rationals converges to an irrational

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm doing some set theory and I have three questions. I'm not quite sure how to prove them though.

(a) Show that for any irrational number $x$ there is a sequence of rational numbers $\{r_{i}\}$ such that $r_{i}\rightarrow x$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$

(b) Use (a) to show that there is an injection of the irrationals $\mathbb{R}$ \ $\mathbb{Q}$ into $P(\mathbb{Q})$, the power set of $\mathbb{Q}$.

(c) Show that the cardinality of $P(\mathbb{Q})$ is $c$.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Think of an irrational in decimal notation.  Then, look at the sequence of consisting of the first $i$ decimal places.

Comment: for (a), see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105248/sequence-of-rational-number-converging-to-a-irrational-number-beta/1105250#1105250)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**a)** Given $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, consider $a_n=\frac{\lfloor nx\rfloor}{n}$. For sure, $a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$.

On the other hand, since $r-\lfloor r\rfloor\in[0,1)$,

$$\left|x-a_n\right|\leq\frac{1}{n}\;\Longrightarrow\,\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}\to x.$$
**b)** Given a), any irrational number $x$ can be associated with an increasing sequence of rational numbers converging towards $x$.

**c)** Since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ have the same cardinality (by [Cantor-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), for instance), $P(\mathbb{Q})$ and $P(\mathbb{N})=2^{\mathbb{N}}$ have the same cardinality, where $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ is the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$. By considering the binary representation of any number in $[0,1)$, then using the Cantor-Bernstein theorem again, we have that the cardinality of $2^{\mathbb{N}}$
equals the cardinality of $[0,1)$, that equals the cardinality of $(0,1)$ (by [Hilbert's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel), for instance), that equals the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ since the map $\varphi:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ given by:
$$ \varphi(x) = -\cot(\pi x) $$
is bijective.